# How do I append a textContent with a CSS class inside?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, dom

Hello I am trying to make changes to the below HTML code textContent however it includes a `<i>` tag in it so how can I change the textContent? How do I edit the HTML tag in the script to keep the `<i>` tag class but change only the text that is in it?

This is how the default HTML look like

[image: This is how the default HTML look like]

This is what it looks like after I edited it

[image: This is what it looks like after I edited it]

**HTML Code**

---

```
<a id="notificationUnread" class="dropdown-item">
  <i class="fas fa-envelope mr-2"></i> 0 unread notifications
</a>
```

**Script**

---

```
var notificationUnread = document.getElementById('notificationUnread').textContent = "TEST"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can target the last text node using `lastChild` or `childNodes[lastIndex]`  and change its value using `node.nodeValue="Something"`

```
document.getElementById("notificationUnread").lastChild.nodeValue="Test"
```

or

```
 let nodes=document.getElementById('notificationUnread').childNodes
 nodes[nodes.length-1].nodeValue= "TES"
```

```js
//let nodes=document.getElementById('notificationUnread').childNodes
//nodes[nodes.length-1].nodeValue= "TES"
//Without span
document.getElementById("notificationUnread").lastChild.nodeValue="Test Without span"
//With span
document.querySelector("#notificationUnread2 > .text-notification").innerText="Test with span"
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--without span -->
<a id="notificationUnread" class="dropdown-item">
  <i class="fas fa-bell mr-2"></i> 0 unread notifications
</a>

<br>
<!--with span -->
<a id="notificationUnread2" class="dropdown-item">
  <i class="fas fa-bell mr-2"></i>
  <span class="text-notification">0 unread notifications</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Hello thanks for the help. But I would like to ask if it happens to be neither the .firstChild or .lastChild how am I able to rectify that?

Comment: you should wrap around the text with span and give class or id and then use selector to target it and change it.

Comment: For example <a id ="notificationUnread" class=dropdown-item"> <i class="fas fa-bell mr-2"></i><span id="testClass">Test</span>?

Comment: i have updated the answer please check it with span and without span

Comment: Alright thank you so much for the detailed explanation. I will take a look at the codes and try to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the html inside your a tag, use this:

```
var notificationUnread = document.getElementById('notificationUnread').innerHTML = "your html here";
```

otherwise you can change the text only with replacing innerHTML to innerText

Comment: Hello I have tried using .innerHTML but this will remove the <i> tag along with it leaving only just the "text".

Comment: Then use the innerText attribut --> var notificationUnread = document.getElementById('notificationUnread').innerText = "your Text here";

Comment: Hello I have tried both .innerText and .innerHTML but the above solution by using .lastChild.nodeValue works for me. Thank you for the help really appreciate the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping the text you want to change in a `<span>`

```
<a id="notificationUnread" class="dropdown-item">
  <i class="fas fa-envelope mr-2"></i> <span class="link-text">0 unread notifications<span>
</a>
```

```
document.querySelector('#notificationUnread .link-text').innerText = "TEST"
```